# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: listinfo

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem getting access sqldp
it shows table doestn't exist
but it works in debugging mode i dont know why and they are in same dir

```
import sqlite3
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_dir = (BASE_DIR + '\\app.db')
def getalldate():
   db=sqlite3.connect("app.db")
   cr=db.cursor()
   cr.execute("SELECT * FROM listinfo")
   result=cr.fetchall()
   print(result)
getalldate()
```

Comment: When you seeking help with Python run-time error, you post the error trace.

Answer (score 0):

don't use single quotation marks to refer to the table name
it should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM listinfo"
```

Comment: thanks but it still don't work